# Infinite loop, program ignoring lines

Tags: c

I need a little help im sort of new to C programming. I'm having some trouble, for some reason the program won't read the line that im trying to take `choice` as input from the user which is causing me to have infinite loop neither the menu is printing.

Also stuff like this happen with me a lot of the time like when I copy my friends' code how it is it dosent run any loops even my teacher doesn't know why so if you can help in this too please do .

```
    #include <stdio.h> 
    #include <stdlib.h> 
    #include <time.h> 
    #include <string.h>

    int main (){
      int choice ,score=0; 
      char name [30]; 

      puts("Welcome to our game , Have fun !\n ");
      puts("Enter your name");
      scanf("%c",name);

      printf("1-Start new game\t2-show recorde\n3-Help         \t4-Show score\n5-Reset score   \t6-Quit game");
      scanf("%d",choice);

      while(choice!=6){

        switch(choice){
        case 1 : 
          break;
        case 2 : 
          break;
        case 3 : 
          break;
        case 4 :
          break;
        default :
          puts("\n invalid input ");
          break;
        }//end switch
      }//end while loop
   }//end main
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Very important: Indendation matters. If you start everyline at column 1 you cannot see anything about the structure. That is unreadable and hardly maintainable. Don't do it. Apply proper indentation instead.

Comment: Please provide information about input you provide and what is expected output as well as the output you get instead.

Comment: Any feedback here? If an answer solves your question you might think about accepting it.

Comment: sorry I'm not used to this. thank a lot great help and sorry again .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your usage of `scanf`is wrong.

```
scanf("%c",name);
```

Format specifier `%c` is not suitable to read a string. It only reads 1 single character.
The other members of `name` array will be untouched and as local variables are not initialized to 0, that is not a valid nul-terminated string.

As soon as you try to print `name` or perform any string operations with it, this will result in undefined behaviour.

As a result, whatever you type after first character, stays in input buffer and is fetched during next read attempt.

To fix this, use format specifier `%s`.

When you now try to read the choice as an integer

```
scanf("%d",choice);
```

the input buffer contains remaining letters and also `\n` from first call, which does not match any number.
After the call `choice` is not modified and still contains its indetermined content (You don't initialize it)

You should **always** check return value of `scanf` to see how many parameters were read. It would show you that it didn't find any value.

Besides that, you also provide invalid parameter. You must provide the address of an integer. This is undefined behaviour.

This is the reason why you always enable warnings in your compiler. It should warn you about this error.

To fix this, use

```
int ret = scanf(" %d", &choice);
if (ret != 1)
  // error handling, try again, etc.
```

Note the space in the format string to skip whitespace including `\n`.

Finally, you enter your loop with a "random" value in `choice` and never try to read again. How would you expect to leave the loop without this?

If your teacher really doesn't know why, the missing indentation might be a reason.